# External PSU (monitor) coil whine only when dark color are on screen

Tags: display, power-supply, noise

I have a [Philips Brilliance 258B6QUEB](https://www.philips.com.au/c-p/258B6QUEB_75/brilliance-lcd-monitor-with-usb-c-dock) monitor which has an external PSU that whines quite notably, but only when the content on the screen is dark-ish.

Take for example these three color gradients: This [clouds](https://uigradients.com/#Clouds) gradient will not produce the whine, while both the [stellar](https://uigradients.com/#Stellar) and the [moonrise](https://uigradients.com/#Moonrise)
gradients will. As in, if I'm on a dark gradient, the noise is consistenly present, when switching to a bright gradient, the noise disappears completely, and when going to a dark gradient again, the noise reappears. Even stranger, as I browse through gradients, the noise has a slightly different pitch depending on the color.

Any idea why this happens, and more importantly, how to avoid it? The problem is not restricted to the web-browser, a dark colored desktop image produces the whine.

**Edit:** I have the same monitor at work, but it does not produce the whining noise. Is it a faulty PSU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been somehow related to the PSU, as the new one provided by Philips does not have the same issue.